# Get the data type of JSON element in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing, primitive-types

I get a JSON value from Kafka queue and I want to get the right data type to save it in the DB.

Value can be: `String`, `int`, `double` or array.

How can i detect automatically the right datatype and create a Java Object from it?

My first steps:

check if json is an array or not:

```
if (jsonValue.isJsonPrimitive()) {

     // create new Object
     //ToDo need to parse int, double not only to string
      new ValueObject(time,jsonValue.getAsString);

    } else if (jsonValue.isJsonArray()) {

     //create new Object
     //ToDo need to parse int, double string
     new ValueObject(time,jsonValue.getAsJsonArray());
}
```

How can I design the `ValueObject` class to convert the value to the corresponding data type and return the right object?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Yes, I use Gson.

I get the value of JSON: jsonValue = jsonTree.getAsJsonObject().get("value");

An now I have to check the value. If it is an array, get the right datatyp and create a java object with time and array value. If it is only primitv value do the same

Comment: Doesn't the column in the database determine what type you should save it as?

Comment: No, its a TimeSeriesDatabase i need to parse it bevor storing

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
//this instanciates an object of the getClass() method output
Object output = jsonValue.getClass().cast(jsonValue);
```

if that didn't work, you can try `instanceof`:

```
if(jsonValue instanceof int){
    int output = (int) jsonValue;
}...
```

I hope that will do.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jackson lib, you can do like this:

```
JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
        Iterator<String> fields = rootNode.fieldNames();
        while(fields.hasNext()){
            String field = fields.next();

            JsonNode  obj = rootNode.get(field);
            
            System.out.println("value " + obj);
            if (obj.isInt()) {
                System.out.println("Integer");
            }
            if (obj.isDouble()) {
                System.out.println("Double");
            }
            if (obj.isTextual()) {
                System.out.println("String");
            }
        }
```